# Migrating a Create React App (Webpack) to NX and Vite - URI malformed at decodeURI

Tags: typescript, monorepo, vite

This is going to be a tricky one because there's a lot going on in here. Therefore, I'll try to be as succinct as possible not to overload you with too much information.

I'm currently in the process of ditching a decent-sized Create React App Monorepo managed with Bolt Package Manager and Yarn into an nx monorepo managed with Vite.

I've created a blank project and began moving the projects one by one. I was able to successfully migrate a storybook project (Webpack), but not the main app which I'm trying to run it in Vite:

I'm currently being hit by a decodeURI malformed problem. I have no idea what it is causing it.

```
C:\Users\asili\Documents\Programming\schon\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-3daf770c.js:57562
        let url = decodeURI(removeTimestampQuery(req.url)).replace(NULL_BYTE_PLACEHOLDER, '\0');
URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURI (<anonymous>)
    at viteTransformMiddleware (C:\Users\asili\Documents\Programming\schon\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-3daf770c.js:57562:19)
    at call (C:\Users\asili\Documents\Programming\schon\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-3daf770c.js:46063:7)
    at next (C:\Users\asili\Documents\Programming\schon\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-3daf770c.js:46007:5)
    at C:\Users\asili\Documents\Programming\schon\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-3daf770c.js:57212:28
    at viteServePublicMiddleware (C:\Users\asili\Documents\Programming\schon\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-3daf770c.js:57251:9)
    at call (C:\Users\asili\Documents\Programming\schon\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-3daf770c.js:46063:7)
    at next (C:\Users\asili\Documents\Programming\schon\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-3daf770c.js:46007:5)
    at next (C:\Users\asili\Documents\Programming\schon\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-3daf770c.js:45985:14)
    at next (C:\Users\asili\Documents\Programming\schon\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-3daf770c.js:45985:14)
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "schon",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.6",
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.8.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.44.0",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.11.0",
    "@material-table/core": "^4.3.11",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@material-ui/system": "^4.12.1",
    "@nivo/calendar": "^0.74.0",
    "@nivo/core": "^0.74.0",
    "@nivo/line": "^0.74.0",
    "@nivo/tooltip": "^0.74.0",
    "@reach/router": "^1.3.4",
    "auth0-js": "^9.18.0",
    "aws-appsync-auth-link": "^3.0.7",
    "aws-appsync-subscription-link": "^3.0.9",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1046.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "d3-array": "^3.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.27.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "formik-persist": "^1.1.0",
    "framer-motion": "^5.4.5",
    "fraql": "^1.2.1",
    "graphql": "^16.1.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "immer": "^9.0.7",
    "linkifyjs": "^3.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "logrocket": "^2.1.2",
    "material-table": "^1.69.3",
    "msw": "^0.36.3",
    "password-validator": "^5.2.1",
    "randomcolor": "^0.6.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-dropzone-uploader": "^2.11.0",
    "react-elastic-carousel": "^0.11.5",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-google-docs-viewer": "^1.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^8.32.5",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.1",
    "react-loading-skeleton": "^3.0.1",
    "react-prerendered-component": "^1.2.4",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.7",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "suneditor": "^2.41.3",
    "suneditor-react": "^3.3.1",
    "sw-precache": "^5.2.1",
    "tiny-slider-react": "^0.5.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "use-debounce": "^7.0.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "validate-password": "^1.0.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^13.0.4",
    "@babel/core": "7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.12.13",
    "@nrwl/cli": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/jest": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/linter": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/node": "^13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
    "@nrwl/react": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/storybook": "^13.3.0",
    "@nrwl/tao": "^13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/web": "13.2.4",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "^13.2.4",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "~6.3.0",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.4.0",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "~6.3.0",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "~6.3.0",
    "@storybook/react": "~6.3.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "7.0.2",
    "@types/auth0-js": "^9.14.5",
    "@types/jest": "27.0.2",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "@types/react": "17.0.30",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.9",
    "@types/react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.2",
    "@types/tiny-slider-react": "^0.3.3",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.3",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~4.33.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh": "^1.3.1",
    "babel-jest": "27.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "cypress": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.26.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
    "jest": "27.2.3",
    "nx-plugin-vite": "^1.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "storybook-theme-toggle": "^0.1.2",
    "ts-jest": "27.0.5",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3",
    "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "vite": "^2.7.1",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^3.3.17"
  }
}
```

Base tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@schon/typings": ["libs/components/src/typings/index.ts"],
      "@schon/components": ["libs/components/src/index.ts"],
      "@schon/utils": ["libs/components/src/utils/index.ts"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

And this is vite's tsconfig.json:

```
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Here's vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [reactRefresh(), tsconfigPaths()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      stream: 'stream-browserify',
    },
  },
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Ayuda a la gestión administrativa y a la
      evaluación del estudiante bajo el nuevo sistema de competencias. ¡Regístrate ya!"
    />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>
      Schon - Plataforma educativa para evaluar a los estudiantes usando el
      sistema de competencias.
    </title>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script
      async
      src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-174022724-1"
    ></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-174022724-1');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->

    <!-- CUSTOM DOWN BELOW-->
    <!-- 
      add entry for snowpack, only used in dev, it is pruned in production.
    -->
    <script type="module" src="/src/index.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? I'll try starting a fresh project and install dependencies one by one... If that doesn't work, then I'll try Snowpack instead.

Webpack takes about 3-4 minutes to start the dev server and that's intolerable for development.

Edit:
I wanted to add that I've been only adding a single empty React file (after rendering the DOM) and it will load that chunk and throw me the error.

Comment: Oh man, I just found out that it was true. The index.html was the one with problems. I did a drop-in from the one that I had from Webpack and that spiraled a series of issues.

Answer (score 5):

remove `%PUBLIC_URL%` from the link tags in your `index.html`. vite doesn't use this placeholder.

That should fix this `URI Malformed` Error

Answer (score 4):

***UPDATE:***

Nx has now added vite support and generators being released in version 15.2. https://nx.dev/packages/vite

We are removing vite and react from Nxext and any users using nxext will have migrations to NX vite

Previous recommendation:

*Note: im a core contributor to Nxext*

I think this project might be good for you https://nxext.dev/docs/react/overview. We recently just wrote the vite plugin for NX and got react working.

If you need any help I'm happy to pair program to resolve this for you

Comment: This is great news! Is it possible to use it with `postcss` and `tailwind@3`?

Comment: I just tried to install it and get the following error: `Unable to resolve @nxext/react:app.
Cannot find module '/Users/knf/dev/test/node_modules/@nxext/react/generators.json'`

Comment: have you installed @nxext/react also yes tailwind does work

Comment: @knoefel if issue stays can you share the logs on https://github.com/nxext/nx-extensions/issues please

Comment: Thx @Jordan Hall! Somebody was quicker than me, as there is already an [issue](https://github.com/nxext/nx-extensions/issues/415) present. 

Comment: Yea, its been fixed this morning - could you retest the issue now :) @knoefel

Answer (score 1):

All set!!

The problem was (indeed) the wrong index.html. Do not just post your `index.html` from Webpack as it won't work.

I reverted it to the one from Vite and it worked!